# When is the interval parameter of dbms_job.submit reevaluated?

Tags: oracle, plsql, scheduling, jobs

In [Oracle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database) we can submit a job to the job queue using the following code:

```
DECLARE
    X   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SYS.DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT (
        job         => X,
        what        => 'SYSTEM.INSERTDATE;',
        next_date   => SYSDATE,
        interval    => 'SYSDATE+0.1/(24*60)'
    );
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Now my question is when the ***interval*** parameter is reevaluated? Before the job execution or after the job execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_job.htm

**interval**

Date function, evaluated immediately **before** the job starts running.